# how to get fixed value from sql query string by java mysql driver?

Tags: java, mysql, driver

I want to parse this sql by mysql-connector-java lib

```sql
select 1 as a, 'b' as b, now() as c from dual
```

I've already tried by java.sql.ResultSetMetaData, but get column name as `'a','b','c'` instead of `1,'b', now()`.

```java
Method getField;
        boolean accessible;
        try {
            getField = ResultSetMetaData.class.getDeclaredMethod("getField", int.class);
            accessible = getField.isAccessible();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if (!accessible) {
            getField.setAccessible(true);
        }
        try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = statement.getMetaData();
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, metaData.getColumnCount())
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    try {
                        Field field = (Field) getField.invoke(metaData, i);
                        // this is not i want
                        field.getName();
                        // this is not i want
                        metaData.getColumnName(i);
                        // this is empty
                        metaData.getColumnLabel(i);

                        // my own entity
                        return field;
                    } catch (SQLException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (!accessible) {
                getField.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to fetch fixed value by driver? or other methods, please help the one who come near to a breakdown.

Comment: you will get column name as `'a','b','c'` only but you should get value as 1, 'b' and today's date

Comment: 1, 'b', now() can only get by ResultSet?

Comment: yes, it should be get by ResultSet as metadata will give column name and other meta information but not actual data

Comment: i could not understand, could you show some code plz?

Comment: something like `resultset.getString(metaData.getColumnName(i));`

Comment: that will get actual value, like now(), will get current date, but I want to get now() as column name

Comment: if you want now() as column name then replace `now() as c` with `now()`

Comment: *"but I want to get now() as column name"* wierd idea how are you going to use `now()` as column name in the application to get the data...  To much thinking and workaround code is needed as now() returns in `'yyyy:mm:hh hh:mm:ss'` format better reconsider your idea....